# How to wait for a loop creating streams to finish before saving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I have a problem with knowing when the loop is finished,

```
app.post('/api/books', upload.array('images'), function(req, res) {
    let book = req.body.book;
    let arr = [];

    // GridFS get connection with DB   
    var gfs = gridfsstream(conn.db);
    var writestream;

    for (i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: req.files[i].originalname
        });
        fs.createReadStream('uploads/' + req.files[i].filename).pipe(writestream);
        writestream.on("close", function(file) {
            console.log(file.filename + "stored successfully into mongodb using gridfs");
        });
        writestream.on("error", function(file) {
            console.log(file.filename + "not stored into mongodb using gridfs");
        });

        base64(writestream.name, function(response) {
            arr.push(response);
        });
    }

    book.images = arr;
    Book.addBook(book, function(err, book) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(book);
    });
});
```

The problem is: The array arr is empty when I do

```
book.images = arr
```

I need wait the for loop be finished , but how can i do that?

I know this works because i already put a `console.log()` and works correctly

```
base64(writestream.name, function(response) {
    arr.push(response);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably best to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) here, but you need to wrap each of the "files" in a Promise and return resolved based on when the `writeStream` in each is completed or errors:

```
app.post('/api/books', upload.array('images'), function(req,res) {
  let book = req.body.book;
  var gfs = gridfsstream(conn.db);

  Promise.all(
    req.files.map(function(file) => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
          filename: file.originalname
        });

        fs.createReadStream('uploads/'+file.filename).pipe(writestream);

        writestream.on("error",reject);
        writestream.on("close",function() {
           base64(writestream.name, function(response) {
             resolve(response);
           });
        });

      })
    })
  )
  .then(function(images) {
    book.images = images;
    Book.addBook(book,function(err,book) {
      if (err) throw err; // or whatever
      res.json(book)
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) => {
    // Deal with errors
  });
});
```

That involves no additional dependencies, however you could alternately use [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) as an additional dependency:

```
app.post('/api/books', upload.array('images'), function(req,res) {
  let book = req.body.book;
  var gfs = gridfsstream(conn.db);

   async.map(
     req.files,
     function(file,callback) {
        var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
          filename: file.originalname
        });

        fs.createReadStream('uploads/'+file.filename).pipe(writestream);

        writestream.on("error",callback);
        writestream.on("close",function() {
           base64(writestream.name, function(response) {
             callback(null,response);
           });
        });                      
     },
     function(err,images) {
       if (err) throw err;

       book.images = images;
       Book.addBook(book,function(err,book) {
         if (err) throw err; // or whatever
         res.json(book)
       });
     }
   );
});
```

So they look pretty similar, and basically they are doing the same thing. In each case the "loop" is now a [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which passes in the current filename as an argument and returns an array of the transformed response, which is in this case the output from your `base64` function. They key here is that the `resolve` or `callback` is basically in control of when things happen.

In the case using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a basic JavaScript [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the array, which is essentially returning an "array of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)" which all implement the `reject` and `resolve` functions which are then called by the respective handlers on the stream.

Here the "Promises" all execute and return there results within the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and pass the output array to the block with `.then()`, which has the content and can then pass to your method to update/create as may be the case.

In the [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) example, this rather uses a `callback` argument which is again supplied to the event handlers on the stream. In exactly the same way, the final block receives the output or error, and can again pass to your method to persist the data.

There is a slight difference in the actual execution of calls, but both essentially apply the same principle that we "signal" output has completed to the mechanism providing the "loop", so that we know when "all" have completed.